# Create an associative function

Tags: php

Function: sortFunc
Parameter(s): Associative Array
Given an associative array using full-names as keys and annual salaries as values; in a table format, print out the name and corresponding salary of each individual in increasing order (from lowest salary to the highest).

I did this:

```
$salary = array(
    "Peter" => "37000",
    "Ben" => "35000",
    "Joe" => "43000"
);
asort($salary);
print_r ($salary);
```

which outputs what I want.
When I try to put it in a function:

```
function sortFunc($array) {
    return sort($array);
}

print_r (sortFunc(array("Peter" => "37", "Ben" => "35", "Joe" => "43")));
```

The output is 1. Can somebody tell me why the output is 1 instead of the associative array sorted out.

Comment: The return value of [`sort(...)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) (and other `*sort` functions) is a boolean, as explained in the answers below. Your function is not equivalent to your free-standing code.

Answer (score 1):

`asort` function returns bool, see PHP doc: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php, in your case, is returning `true` which is converted to `1`. You have to return the array converted, so the code:

```
function sortFunc($array) {
    asort($array);
    return $array;
}
$salary = array("Peter" => "37", "Ben" => "35", "Joe" => "43");
print_r(sortFunc($salary));
```

`asort` re-orders the array which is passed as parameter and it changes the array, so after an `asort` you get the ordered array in the in the array you passed as a parameter

Answer (score 1):

According to a manual all `*sort` functions operate on array passed **by reference** and return `true` or `false` as a result.

So:

```
return sort($array);
```

returns result of a function call, but not a modified `$array`.

You have to return array **explicitly**:

```
function sortFunc($array) {
    sort($array);
    return $array;
}
```